# Python ImportError: No module named 'server'

Tags: python, pip, stratum

I am trying to install stratum module in python 3.5 on Ubuntu. But I get the error

> ImportError: No module named 'server'

My installation command is

> python3 setup.py install

Any suggestion how to solve this?

Comment: Are you using `pip`?

Comment: No pip does not work as I get the error "urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: SSL is required"

Answer (score 1):

Okay, another method:

1. First, make sure that your system packages are up-to-date by running these following apt commands in terminal:

   - `sudo apt update`
   - `sudo apt upgrade`
2. Install the pip by using apt command:

   - `apt-get install python-pip`
   - Once the installation is completed you can verify that it was successful by using the following command: `pip -V`
3. And after that you can use: `pip install <package_name>`

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/stratum/), it says `Python 2.7 or 2.6` is needed. As you are trying to use python 3.5.

I would suggest going like this ([0.2.15](https://pypi.org/project/stratum/#history) is the latest version), most probably it will work, or at least it will be easier to debug.

```sh
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade

pip3 download stratum==0.2.15
tar xvzf ./stratum-0.2.15.tar.gz
cd stratum-0.2.15
pip3 install .
```

Answer (score -4):

The best way to install some package is to use pip install. So at first u need to PATH python and scripts:

- Hold <kbd>Win</kbd> and press <kbd>Pause</kbd>.
- Click Advanced System Settings.
- Click Environment Variables.
- Append
- C:\Users(your
  username)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32
- C:\Users(your
  username)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts

  to the
  Path variable.
- Restart Command Prompt.

After that u can use `pip install stratum` in `cmd`

Comment: He's using python3.x (which is probably bound to pip3) and running Ubuntu.